# python sqlite3 syntax error with string when doing update

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I have this function in python that attempts to update the table with a string:

```
table.execute("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " +
                       colName + "=" + colVal +
                        " WHERE " + name + "=(" + val + ")")
```

It always return the error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Look": syntax error.

How should I process my "val" value so that the string can be added into the database?

==update==
tried this query and it didn't work either:

```
table.execute("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " +
                        colName + "=" + colValue +
                        " WHERE " + name + "= ?", (val,))
```

Comment: "How should I process my "val" value" Use parametrized query instead of vulnerable string concatenation.

Comment: @DeepSpace could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: `print("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " +
                       colName + "=" + colVal +
                        " WHERE " + name + "=(" + val + ")")` and share the result.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are major flaws in using direct variables in sql queries:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Read up more on them. But if you do want to make your code work you can do the following change:

```
table.execute("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " +
                       colName + "='" + colVal + 
                        "' WHERE " + name + "=('" + val + "')")
table.commit()
```

Since val/colVal are strings being passed to the query so it should be escaped.

Have added sample example here which works: https://gist.github.com/vi3k6i5/869d299e8afe99593b79ae41051ebf63

As @Deepspace pointed out in the comment, SQL directly executed on db is not safe.

Hence a good way to do all this is to use an ORM. Something like [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [SQLalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Go through their examples they are pretty simple. And they have their own structure to make changes to db. Update/Insert/Delete everything.

Comment: `var = "' OR '1'='1"` There goes your database.

Comment: @DeepSpace I know that. Just pointing out what ze is doing wrong in his code. How will ze learn otherwise?

Comment: @acbh : did you skip colVal as well with quotes ??

Comment: @VikashSingh my colVal is fine, it is just a word "name"

Comment: @acbh do this: `print("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " +
                       colName + "=" + colVal +
                        " WHERE " + name + "=('" + val + "')")` and share what comes out.

Comment: UPDATE Table SET record=(' name is right ')  WHERE time=(' time(min) ')

Comment: this didn't give me an error but the table wasn't updated either

Comment: you need to commit the changes. `table.commit()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130952/discussion-between-vikash-singh-and-acbh).

Comment: @DeepSpace can you please remove the downvote if you feel the answer is explanatory.